# How to create Balloon Marker xib View in ios-charts?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, draw, balloon

i have XIB to display multiple data show on chart.
but i do't set ballon mark and when click last point screen cut in my XIB.
here attach to screenshot to better understand my issue.
[image]

Second image is here
[image]

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please use it BalloonMarker.swift https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Swift/Components/BalloonMarker.swift

```
let marker:BalloonMarker = BalloonMarker(color: UIColor.black, font: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Medium", size: 12)!, textColor: UIColor.white, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 7.0))
 marker.chartView = lineChartView
 marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 75.0, height: 50.0)
 lineChartView.marker = marker
 lineChartView.drawMarkers = true
```

Comment: open class BalloonMarker: MarkerImage
this for MarkerImage , i need for XIBView.

Comment: please check image i have create Ballomarker for this swift file.

Comment: Thanks @HimanshuPatel
but i need to set XIB on ballon and my XIB is dynamic.

Comment: @KhushaliOS This is balloonMarker is not static view on xib it's dynamic.